# Opening Office 2010 documents from C# error

Tags: c#, file, mime-types

I am trying to load office documents for a user by

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = MIMETypesDictionary[fileExt];
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(fileArray);
```

and my MIMETypesDictionary has this (abbreviated)

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> MIMETypesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
        {"doc", "application/msword"},
        {"docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},
        ...
        {"xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},  
        {"xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"}
        ...
      };
```

doc and xls files work great. Docx and xlsx files error in the client application.

Excel errors

```
Excel found unreadable content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workfbook?
```

Word errors

```
The file filename.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.
```

if I click Yes, it loads and the docs looks okay. This error won't fly for users of course. Am I using the right mime types for these files? I also tried application/vnd.ms-word.document.12, application/vnd.ms-excel.12 and application/octet-stream and got the same errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just using "application/octet-stream" for the content type. I've just written something for streaming files and using this alone was sufficient for docx files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

resolved! had to build out the response code

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = MIMETypesDictionary[fileExt];
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(fileArray);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

and i kept the octet-stream values for the file types and it works great!